# Database change automation for CI?

Tags: database, frameworks, continuous-integration, change-management

Our application stack looks something like `Java 8` out of `Tomcat 7`, several distinct `Postgres` databases, `Maven` for build and `Jenkins` for `CI`. I have fully automated my team's build process using except for one missing subprocess: **database (schema and/or data) changes**. Once a change is committed to version control, a new build is kicked off in Jenkins and its resulting artifacts deployed in the build environment. I also have some scripts that deploy configuration file changes, should there be any, which is rare but even that case scenario is covered.

However, database schema changes still have to be applied manually. So if a an entity class contains a variable mapped via `Hibernate` to a column that has not yet been added in the database, the deployment fails until the change is applied manually. Needless to say, I hate it and need to overcome this irksome intervention.

I am wondering if there is any framework that integrates database changes, using `convention over configuration`. I am currently writing my own script to scan a versioned directory for conventionally formatted files containing schema or data changes (in the form of SQL statements) in `Python` but I would rather not reinvent the wheel if such a framework exists already because this scenario should be something many before me had to deal with.

Comment: Asking for a framework gives your question a high chance of getting closed by the community here, since asking for third party resources or tools is off-topic here on this site (there is a predefined close vote for this!). You might save your question by editing it and ask for an approach instead for a tool.

Comment: Yeah it just turns into an opportunity for advertising.

Comment: while i understand the strict limitations of this particular forum, i find the question legitimate. where else on SE should I ask this same question ?

Comment: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7253/where-does-my-tool-question-go - but think about what I wrote, if you ask for an approach instead for a tool, your question can IMHO be made on-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if Hibernate can create its own changesets based on the change in the mapping between model and db,  but in the Java world I believe the go-to tool is LiquiBase (http://www.liquibase.org). I've had experience with this and it works well enough.

Comment: Flyway is another popular choice for schema migrations https://flywaydb.org/